# Understanding Recursive algorithm using FIB

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, fibonacci-numbers

I am studying for an exam, and I came across this question, I think I got the answer correct, just need some validation.

```
    Algorithm FIB(n):

    if n = 0 or n = 1
   then f = n
    else
        f = FIB(n-1) + FIB(n-2)
    endif
    return f
```

If `FIB(7)` is called how many calls are there to `FIB(3)`?
My answer is 5 because  `FIB(0)` or `FIB(1)`  just returns n, so you do not add them. Then you just add the remainder which I believe is 5. Is this the correct way of looking at this problem or is their a mathematical/formulaic approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the recursion tree(the tree is due to the calling of the function) and try to see if there is a recursion for counting it. Your intuition is not correct, try to count FIB(3) in FIB(8) (the remainder is 6 and the answer is 8)

I write it here because i can not do comments :(.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just looked up how to draw a FIB recursion tree and it helped me greatly, much appreciated.

Comment: I am glad i could help. I was going to a much general question. Hoy many times does Fib(n) is in Fib(m) if $n\leq m$?
Good luck in your exam.

Comment: I have no idea what the formula would be for that, I just know how to do when n is assigned to a number, is there a specific formula?

Comment: Yes its a very well known number(sucesion), indeed you have it on your question(preety direct hint :P). See the recursion tree again :)

Comment: I looked up a formula and it said that it is: A(subscript:n-1) + 1 + A(subscript:n-2) but I don't get how that would work in this problem? What would the A's be if I wanted so see how many times FIB(8) calls FIB(3)

Comment: Cause if you want a greater number you just can not draw the tree..You must find a better way to do it..Suppose you want to count how many times Fib(13) is in Fib(80)..Its a better way than actually draw the tree. Is not it?
BtW, it looks a lot like fibonacci.Indeed i asked you having in mind that if you want to count how many times Fib(n) is in Fib(m) the answer is Fib(m-n+1).(it can be proven by induction or see the relation in the tree)